# Fatal error on soap Exception

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

i make a client for a soap call and whenever for any reason the remote server is not responsible to my request it makes an error ,

here is my code:

```
$this->register_link = new SoapClient('http://test.com:8020/WebService/service.asmx?wsdl',array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'trace' => 1,'exceptions' => TRUE, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
```

and even on creating soapclinet  **some times** this error happen:

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL Couldn't load from .....
```

so the problem and the question is ,
why it makes fatal error and not exception i googled and other developers say to save the wsdl locally but after i call the link locally the problem still not solved , and some times it makes fatal error ,
some developers say to change wsdl cashing options but it not helped me

so what should i do,that if i cant connect to server it not make fatal error and make an exception to i can handle that

Comment: It's looks like WSDL is invalid. Can you provide WSDL?

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski yes its occurred sometimes, i write test.com instead of my url and the url is responsible but sometimes because of network problems its make fatal error